# Why does my Python deployment package contain so many folders?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip, aws-lambda

I followed the instructions from an Amazon AWS Lambda help document titled, "Creating a Deployment Package (Python)"

`pip install requests -t /path/to/project-dir`

It was successful, and the resulting deployment package works, but it contains 10 folders: urllib3, chardet, certifi, idna, requests, and an accompanying "dist-info" folder for each.

All of the folders are required in order to compile the code in an AWS Lambda function. Omitting any folders causes a compile error in AWS Lambda.

However, the following project from two years ago has a similar distribution package, where there is only one folder named "requests" and one "dist-info" folder, for a total of just two folders:
https://github.com/cpiggott/LambdaToSlack

I used Python version 3.7.0b1 from January 2018, on Windows 10. I also tried this on a different machine with Python 2.7.14 on Windows 7, but got the same result.

I looked at the command line options and tried a couple that seemed possible, but it didn't make a difference:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#options

So I wonder why does my distribution package require ten folders when the other one only requires two? Is there any parameter or other procedure I can use to end up with less folders?

Comment: Simply because LambdaToSlack does not contain a proper dependencies management and you might get into dependency problems when using or deploying it.

Comment: @KlausD. Thank you. I had assumed there was something wrong with my deployment package because it was different than the other, but now I can see that they are really not the same thing. Thanks again.